# Fragment take too long to show when I use listview inside

Tags: android, fragment

This is my fragment class:

```
public class FragmentDdayMonthly extends Fragment {

    ListView lvFrequency;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dday_monthly, container, false);

        ArrayList<MonthlyModel> monthlyModels = new ArrayList<MonthlyModel>();
        monthlyModels.add(null);
        lvFrequency = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_frequency);
        DDayMonthlyListAdapter adapter = new DDayMonthlyListAdapter(getActivity(),monthlyModels,lvFrequency);
        lvFrequency.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
```

This is adapter:

```
public class DDayMonthlyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<MonthlyModel> monthlyModels;
    ListView listView;

    public DDayMonthlyListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<MonthlyModel> monthlyModels, ListView listView) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.monthlyModels = monthlyModels;
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return monthlyModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // inflate the GridView item layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_monthly_list, parent, false);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Layout **fragment_dday_monthly** just have a Listview. And here is layout of Listview's item (**R.layout.item_monthly_list**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frequency_choose_container_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dday_activity_divider"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/frequency_choose_container_1">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_chosen_month"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spinner_frequency_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_chosen_month_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spin_chosen_month"
            android:src="@drawable/add_ic_arrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frequency_choose_container_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dday_activity_divider">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_chosen_month"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spinner_frequency_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monthly"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp14_text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_chosen_month_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_chosen_month"
            android:src="@drawable/add_ic_arrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frequency_monthly_picker_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frequency_choose_container_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_frequency_date_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_choose_container_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rb_frequency_date_5"
            android:background="@drawable/dday_activity_divider">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_chosen_date_2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spinner_chosen_date_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp14_text_size"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_chosen_date_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spin_chosen_date_2"
                android:src="@drawable/add_ic_arrow" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_choose_container_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rb_frequency_date_5"
            android:background="@drawable/dday_activity_divider">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_chosen_date_1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spinner_chosen_date_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp14_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_chosen_date_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_chosen_date_1"
                android:src="@drawable/add_ic_arrow" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_frequency_week_n_month_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_choose_container_2"
            android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/daily_choose_container_child_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rb_frequency_week_n_month_5"
            android:background="@drawable/dday_activity_divider">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_chosen_day_child_6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Weekly"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp14_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_chosen_day_child_6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_chosen_day_child_6"
                android:src="@drawable/add_ic_arrow" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/daily_choose_container_child_7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/daily_choose_container_child_6"
            android:background="@drawable/dday_activity_divider">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_chosen_day_child_7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monday"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp14_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_chosen_day_child_7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_chosen_day_child_7"
                android:src="@drawable/add_ic_arrow" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_ic_delete" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_delete"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_delete"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_add"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_ic_add" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I just inflate view to fragment. I dont do any heavy task, but the fragment load so long, it take 1-2 second to be shown. Please help me to fix it!

Comment: how many items do you have in your list ?

Comment: not sure but this is a big layout you have there, does it have any large images?

Comment: @Fakher I just add a null item to inflate view as you can see in the onCreateView.

Yazan Nope I just have an small arrow image like spinner's arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inflating , setting adapter in onCreateView do those things in `onViewCreated()` method

```
public class FragmentDdayMonthly extends Fragment {

    ListView lvFrequency;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dday_monthly, container, false);

        ArrayList<MonthlyModel> monthlyModels = new ArrayList<MonthlyModel>();
        monthlyModels.add(null);
        lvFrequency = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_frequency);
        DDayMonthlyListAdapter adapter = new DDayMonthlyListAdapter(getActivity(),monthlyModels,lvFrequency);
        lvFrequency.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
   }
}
```

Like this

```
public class FragmentDdayMonthly extends Fragment {

    ListView lvFrequency;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dday_monthly, container, false);

        return view;
   }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ArrayList<MonthlyModel> monthlyModels = new ArrayList<MonthlyModel>();
         monthlyModels.add(null);
         lvFrequency = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_frequency);
         DDayMonthlyListAdapter adapter = new DDayMonthlyListAdapter(getActivity(),monthlyModels,lvFrequency);
         lvFrequency.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove that `Listview` adapter code, is it working fine?

Comment: yah, of course it work fine but it just show a blank page

Comment: Then I think you have some problem in the adapter class

Comment: Is the layout item_monthly_list too big?

Comment: Have you posted that?

Comment: I tested it and yah, the layout item_monthly_list is too big. What should I do?

Comment: But, list doesn't contain anything na

Comment: that's right, but null can be counted as an object so I can inflate the layout item_monthly_list to the listview.

Comment: Okay, So try to reduce the item size, we can't do anything other than that as per my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need of passing Arraylist To DDayMonthlyListAdapter as this is not necessary in your case
also you should modify the code as below:

```
public int getCount() {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

This must work as the solution!>..

Comment: What?  `return 0;` in `getCount()` will just cause the `ListView` to display _nothing_.